# How to implement Audio Unit Pattern I/O Pass Through without a Render Callback Function

Tags: ios, audio

Audio Unit Pattern have a I/O Pass Through pattern.How to implement it? Use one RemoteUnit or two? Could someone give me the sample code ?
Apple Develper Document  https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH16-SW21

Comment: You can find answer here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325291/augraphaddnode-10862/36326665#36326665